# Where did Mystique learn her combat skills?

Tags: marvel, x-men

As a mutant, Mystique has Shapeshifter abilities, but she is also a good fighter and has great martial art skills. Per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystique_%28comics%29)

> Mystique is a cunning strategist in terrorist and commando operations, and adept at martial arts and information technology.

My question is where did she learn martial arts and IT? Was it the part of her super powers?

Comment: Are you looking for information from any specific continuity/medium (comics, movies, tv shows, etc)?

Comment: Anything will work. I am interested to know how did she acquire those skills.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Mystique has spent a number of years working with and for the United States government in a variety of civilian capacities. She could have also acquired her military training on those same facilities posing as a soldier and acquiring training illicitly. It is never clearly established where she gained her practical military training.

- Mystique worked for the DARPA program and gained high rank in their Civil Service divisions. She gained her experience and eye for advanced technology there.
- As for her military capacity, she is nearly one hundred years old and could have acquired those skills in a variety of places, since she could appear as a man, she could have easily served in a military capacity in any number of military conflicts.
- Mystique has spent a significant amount of time performing espionage on military facilities, it makes sense she would acquire the skills to better aid in her cover identities as well as their usefulness in her other covert ops activities.
- Mystique once had dozens of covert operation identities, any of which could have explained her skill in military combat, since some were most assuredly military identities. They were later destroyed by the U.S. Government.
- Mystique has also lead a number of metahuman teams which could have furthered her knowledge and expertise in a variety of operations and fields of combat. She has lead the Brotherhood of Evil Mutants, which later became the government-sanctioned Freedom Force.

Comment: At one point, she was working as a spy for the Germans. That's where she met Victor Creed, and it was during that mission that they conceived Graydon Creed.

Comment: Does her ability to impersonate people include their fighting moves? If so, perhaps that also aided her in developing advanced combat skills.

Comment: No, her ability seems strictly limited to physical adaptations, not neurological ones. Her recent animal shapeshifting may include some physiological information (otherwise she couldn't turn into a bird and fly, for example) but trained martial arts skills would seem to be beyond the scope of her transformations, unless we're told otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what continuity you're looking to for answers. For example, in the 2011 live-action film by Matthew Vaughn X-Men: First Class, it seems to be mainly self-taught, with slight guiding by Charles Xavier (Professor X) and Eric Lensherr (Magneto). However, in the animated TV show Wolverine and the X-Men, she is shown as sharing a past in the Weapon X program with Victor Creed (Sabretooth) and James Howlett (Later Logan/Wolverine), where she received a degree of training on top of her time after Weapon X; ergo, time with the Brotherhood and such.